# CPU broken on my late 2013 Macook Pro. Is it worth replacing?

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu, repair, logic

My computer keeps restarting and after taking it into the Apple store and a repair store, both are telling me the CPU needs to be replaced. The Macbook pro is a late 2013 and it's like a $500+ repair. Do you think it's worth replacing or should I just buy a new machine? Also, is the CPU the same as the logic board?

Comment: i edited the description

Comment: Your money , you choose : can’t make the decision for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth paying $500 to fix a 2013 MacBook Pro, because you should be able to sell it for more than $500 if it's in working order. So get it fixed, and you can then decide whether to keep it or sell it and put the proceeds towards a new machine.